# converting Unicode code point numbers to Unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode

I'm using the argparse library in Python 3 to read in Unicode strings from a command line parameter.  Often those strings contain "ordinary" Unicode characters (extended Latin, etc.), but sometimes--particularly when the characters belong to a right-to-left script--it's easier to encode the strings as Unicode code points, like \u0644.  But argparse treats these designators as a sequence of characters, and does not convert them into the character they designate.  For instance, if a command line parameter is

```
... -a "abc\06d2d" ...
```

then what I get in the argparse variable is

```
"abc\06d2d"
```

rather than the expected

```
"abcےd"
```

(the character between the 'c' and 'd' is the yeh baree).  Of course both outcomes are logical, it's just that the second one is the one I want.

I tried to reproduce this in an interpreter, but under most circumstances Python3 automagically converts a string like "abc\06d2d" into "abcےd".  Not so when I read the string using argparse...

I came up with a function to do the conversion, see below.  But I feel like I'm missing something much simpler.  Is there an easier way to do this conversion?  (Obviously I could use str.startswith(), or regex's to match the entire thing, rather than going character by character, but the code below is really just an illustration.  It seems like I shouldn't have to create my own function to do this at all, especially since in some circumstances it seems to happen automatically.)

---------My code to do this follows---------

```
def ParseString2Unicode(sInString):
  """Return a version of sInString in which any Unicode code points of the form 
        \uXXXX (X = hex digit)  
     have been converted into their corresponding Unicode characters.
     Example:
         "\u0064b\u0065" 
     becomes
         "dbe"
  """
  sOutString = ""
  while sInString:
      if len(sInString) >= 6 and \
         sInString[0] == "\\" and \
         sInString[1] == "u" and \
         sInString[2] in "0123456789ABCDEF" and \
         sInString[3] in "0123456789ABCDEF" and \
         sInString[4] in "0123456789ABCDEF" and \
         sInString[5] in "0123456789ABCDEF":
          #If we get here, the first 6 characters of sInString represent
          # a Unicode code point, like "\u0065"; convert it into a char:
          sOutString += chr(int(sInString[2:6], 16))
          sInString = sInString[6:]
      else:
          #Strip a single char:
          sOutString += sInString[0]
          sInString = sInString[1:]
  return sOutString
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you may want to look at is the `raw_unicode_escape` encoding.

```
>>> len(b'\\uffff')
6
>>> b'\\uffff'.decode('raw_unicode_escape')
'\uffff'
>>> len(b'\\uffff'.decode('raw_unicode_escape'))
1
```

So, the function would be:

```
def ParseString2Unicode(sInString):
    try:
        decoded = sInString.encode('utf-8')
        return decoded.decode('raw_unicode_escape')
    except UnicodeError:
        return sInString
```

This, however, also matches other unicode escape sequences, like `\Uxxxxxxxx`. If you just want to match `\uxxxx`, use a regex, like so:

```
import re

escape_sequence_re = re.compile(r'\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}')

def _escape_sequence_to_char(match):
    return chr(int(match[0][2:], 16))

def ParseString2Unicode(sInString):
    return re.sub(escape_sequence_re, _escape_sequence_to_char, sInString)
```

Comment: I think your first method is more or less what I was looking for (and I would probably just call it as SomeString.encode('utf-8').encode('raw_Unicode_escape').  Unfortunately, I'm running Python 3, and this appears to only work in Python 2.  Specifically, in 3 it complains "'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'" at the second step (the step using encode('raw_unicode_escape').  I'll play with this a bit and see if I can come to grips with this diff between P2 and 3...

Comment: Turned out to be simple to fix for Python 3: just use decode() in the second step, rather than encode().  For instance (and leaving out the error testing) sString.encode('utf-8').decode('raw_unicode_escape').

Comment: I'll mark this as the solution (of the type I wanted, i.e. using built-in Python conversion, rather than parsing the string).  For anyone coming here later: See Artyer's version for Python 2, or my tiny revision for Python 3.

Comment: @MikeMaxwell Oops. It was meant to be `decode`. It was just a typo. In Python2, you can just `decode` it straight away.

Answer (score 1):

A concise, flexible way of handling this would be to use a regular expression:

```
return re.sub(
    r"\\u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})",
    lambda m: chr(int(m[1], 16)),
    sInString
)
```

Comment: Thanks--I figured there were more concise methods of writing the function, and yours is certainly that!  I left it non-concise for clarity (and because I was lazy).  But what I'm really after is a way to avoid rolling my own parser--I felt like I was missing some automagic way of doing this that didn't require writing a parser at all.